# Apagar variavel fornecida ao desmarcar Checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Tenho um código que salva em um textarea valores de um checkbox, mas não consigo fazer o valor ser apagado do textarea quando o checkbox é desmarcado.

```js
var checkbox = document.getElementsByName('CP[]');
var teste = [];

function addCheck() {
    for (var i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
        if (checkbox[i].checked == true)
            teste[i] = checkbox[i].value;
    }
 
    document.getElementById("cps").innerHTML = teste;
    var textarea = document.getElementById("cps").value;
}
```

```html
<input name='CP[]' id='CP01' type='checkbox' onclick='addCheck()' value="A">
<input name='CP[]' id='CP01' type='checkbox' onclick='addCheck()' value="B">
<input name='CP[]' id='CP01' type='checkbox' onclick='addCheck()' value="C">
<input name='CP[]' id='CP01' type='checkbox' onclick='addCheck()' value="D">
<input name='CP[]' id='CP01' type='checkbox' onclick='addCheck()' value="E">

<br />

<textarea name='cps' id='cps' cols='8' rows='1' value=''></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tens de fazer algumas alterações:

- `teste[i] = checkbox[i].value;` deve ser `teste.push(checkbox[i].value);` senão vais estar a criar posições vazias dentro da array
- `..."cps").innerHTML = teste;` deve ser `..."cps").innerHTML = teste.join(',');`. Não é fundamental, mas como está é uma conversão de *Tipo*  à bruta.
- coloca `var teste = [];` antes do `for` para re-inicializar a variável com uma array vazia

#### Exemplo:

```js
var checkbox = document.getElementsByName('CP[]');
var cps = document.getElementById("cps");

function addCheck() {
  var teste = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
    if (checkbox[i].checked == true) teste.push(checkbox[i].value);
  }
  cps.innerHTML = teste.join(',');
}
```

```html
<input name='CP[]' id='CP01' type='checkbox' onclick='addCheck()' value="A">
<input name='CP[]' id='CP01' type='checkbox' onclick='addCheck()' value="B">
<input name='CP[]' id='CP01' type='checkbox' onclick='addCheck()' value="C">
<input name='CP[]' id='CP01' type='checkbox' onclick='addCheck()' value="D">
<input name='CP[]' id='CP01' type='checkbox' onclick='addCheck()' value="E">
<br />
<textarea name='cps' id='cps' cols='8' rows='1' value=''></textarea>
```

Comment: Isso mesmo, muito obrigado!

Comment: @Rocha ótimo. Até breve.